# Contradiction with inclusion of $L_p[0,1],L_q[0,1]$? if $1/p+1/q=1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $p<q\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be such that $1/p+1/q=1$ and consider $L_p[0,1]$ ,$L_q[0,1]$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Since $[0,1]$ has finite measure it follows that
$$L_q[0,1] \subset L_p[0,1].$$

Also for any infinite dimensional vector space we must have it's dual must be strictly larger, i.e. $V \subset V^*$

Therefore we must have $L_p[0,1]\subset {L_p}^*[0,1]$ with the inclusion being strict. But by Riesz representation theorem we have that $${L_p}^*[0,1]=L_q[0,1].$$
Combining the results above we get $L_p[0,1]\subset {L_q}[0,1]$ with the inclusion being strict.
This causes contradiction, so which of the above statements is incorrect?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incorrect statement is

> "Also for any infinite dimensional vector space we must have it's dual must be strictly Larger i.e. $V\subset V^*$"

It is not true. You gave a counterexample yourself. Besides the fact that in general the inclusion $V\subset V^*$ doesn't even make sense, as there is no canonical way of seeing the elements of a vector space $V$ as linear functionals over $V$.

Comment: Precisely. I believe the OP got confused with the (correct) statement $V \subset V^{**}$ via the natural identification. +1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is a question here on stack exchange with title "Dual space question" They say that this is the case in that question is that an error. Unfortunately I don't know how to insert the link

Comment: That comment is about algebra, not about functional analysis Yes, the dimension of the **algebraic** dual of a vector space is always at least as big as that of the vector space. When you start considering continuous linear functionals over a topological vector space, that's not true anymore; at the extreme, there exist topological vector spaces where the dual is trivial. When you have a normed space the dual is always "big" in the sense that it separates points (by Hahn-Banach); but it still doesn't make sense to compare then directly in general.